# Recently, I switched to python 3.11 & I'm unable to install kivy & kivymd

Tags: python, kivy

[Here, is the **error** image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3ZrU.png)
Recently, I switched to python 3.11 & I'm unable to install kivy & kivymd.
Luckily, I've big brain & I switched back to python 3.10 & install kivy & its works like a charm.

## **How can I install kivy with python 3.11 ???**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: 3.11 *just* came out. Packages, *especially* C extension-based packages, need some time to come out with updated compatible versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy 2.1.0 officially supports Python versions 3.7 - 3.10.

Source: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to install the not-yet-stable nightly version of Kivy, these work for Python 3.11:

```
python -m pip install kivy --pre --no-deps --index-url  https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
python -m pip install "kivy[base]" --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```

Make sure to update often.